# submit button without reload page in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do i make it not reload page when i click the button

I have 2 form

```
= form_with(model: @favorite_job, url: favorite_jobs_path(job_id: job_id), id: "favorite-{job_id}", remote: true) do |f|
  = f.submit 'Favorite', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-height'
```

and

```
= form_with(model: @favorite_job, url: favorite_jobs_path(job_id: job_id), id: "favorite-{job_id}", remote: true) do |f|
  = f.submit 'Favorite', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-height'
```

with controller

```
def create
    @favorite_job = current_user.favorite_jobs.build(job_id: @job.id)
    @favorite_job.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path) }
      format.js
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @favorite_job = current_user.favorite_jobs.find_by(job_id: @job.id)
    @favorite_job.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path) }
      format.js
    end
  end
```

Comment: If this isn't being sent as an AJAX request then Rails UJS is not working in your app which can happen due to a large number of factors. Check the console for errors and make sure its included in your packs (for Webpacker) or assets if you're still using Sprockets. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#remote-elements

Comment: Also `id: "favorite-{job_id}"` should be id:`id: "favorite-#{job_id}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want a button, you can use:

```
= link_to favorite_jobs_path(job_id: job_id, format: :js),
    method: :post,
    remote: true,
    class: 'btn btn-primary btn-height'
    | Favorite

= link_to favorite_jobs_path(job_id: job_id, format: :js),
    method: :delete,
    remote: true,
    class: 'btn btn-primary btn-height'
    | Unfavorite
```

If you have additional attributes, you can try:

```
= form_with(model: @favorite_job, url: favorite_jobs_path(job_id: job_id, format: :js), id: "favorite-{job_id}", remote: true) do |f|
  = f.input :some_attr
  = f.submit 'Favorite', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-height'
```

Comment: `remote: true` will send a `JS` request. The issue here is most likely that Rails UJS is broken and setting the format will not fix anything.